# Decrypt file that was encrypted using a public key created from PuttyGen

Tags: ssl, decryption

I have a file that our customer encrypted using our public key. I know how to decrypt it using our ppk file programmatically, but I am unsure of how to do this from the command line, or using PuTTYGen (which I don't think supports the decryption of files from the utility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a public key if you don't know how to use it?

The encrypted block probably says in clear text what program/system was used to encrypt it.
It's probably the one that generated your public key.

BTW, I believe I've seem phishing email that used this scheme to try to trick you into downloading and running some "decrypting" software.

Comment: I could write a program to decrypt it but i was hoping for a utility that would quickly allow me to decrypt the file for time's sake.

Comment: something doesn't add up here.  How is it you have a public key and no clue how to use it as part of an encryption system?

Comment: I've only worked with encryption a few times, I don't know much about the whole process. Basically, I have a ppk file (our private key), and a file that our customer sent us which has been encrypted with our public key. I need to know how to decrypt the file (e.g. what is a good utility to use for this)

Comment: google "pgp" for some likely useful information

Comment: thanks, openpgp is much more acceptable for what we're trying to accomplish